# ssh not using agent-forwarded keys

Tags: ssh, unix, ssh-agent

I ssh from `local` to `X`, and I would like to ssh from `X` to `Y` using password-protected RSA keys, with all my private keys being stored on `local`. However,

```
local> ssh -A X
X> ssh Y
Received disconnect: 2: Too many authentication failures
```

This is because I have too many keys in the agent, and it doesn't get to the right key before server `Y` thinks I'm malicious. I can confirm this by removing all keys from my `~/.ssh` except those that are for `X` and `Y`, and then the ssh command works. Now I can't specify the correct key to use with `ssh Y -o IdentiyFile=path` because the right path to the key is on `local`, not on `X`. Furthermore, if I specify `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes`, it never looks for keys provided by the agent, it only looks for keys in the `X:~/.ssh`. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. On system `X`, I create a `~/.ssh/config` section for `Y` which is something like:

```
Host Y
    ...
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_Y.pub
    ...
```

where `~/.ssh/id_Y.pub` is a copy (on `X`) of the public key for local to `Y`. `sshd` only needs to know where the public key is, it will find out everything else it needs from the agent.

Comment: OMG, I've been searching for this solution everywhere!